# Python custom module not found but already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, travis-ci, codecov

I have created a separate file to hold some custom issue classes for my Python file and upon execution of the following command: `coverage run test_syntax.py` it prints out the following error as seen in [this](https://travis-ci.org/Richienb/ROS-Code/jobs/405215755) Travis CI build:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_syntax.py", line 9, in 
    from ros import main as s
  File "/home/travis/build/Richienb/ROS-Code/src/ros/main.py", line 57, in 
    from errors import ConversionError, WrongInput, UnexpectedError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errors'
```

You can find all of the code [here](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/tree/526adf020cf1d89f471b837dc4ff395a4db57913)

Also, I have already cd into the `src` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a relative import like this (second one was needed on my machine to even get to the error you have posted):

```
# in main.py
from .errors import ...
# ros.py
from . import errors
```

Comment: I committed the [changes](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/tree/4a8c2cac92b2915b7ba1d3449b836bbc45711e8d) and it [works](https://travis-ci.org/Richienb/ROS-Code/builds/406051935)! Thank you very much for your help.